# Cell button tableView Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, storyboard, tableview

I have a tableView with Sections and every section got todoitems that u add.
I'm trying to animate in my picture on the todoItem I click with my cell button delegate function. But I really don't know how to connect to just that one item and make it animate.
What I'm trying to get access to is the same access to a cell like I do in didSelectRow but in this cellButtonFunction, since it's the button in the cell I'm gonna press on and not the whole cell.

The thing I wanna accomplish with pressing the button is like this example:

cellPressed.image.ishidden = false
cellPressed.image.animate()

This cell image have an animated class that works set to it, it's just that I need to hit the specific cell for this

Watched a few YouTube videos and researched but I don't get it to work, so I hope you guys can help me

```
extension ViewController: FirstTableViewCellDelegate {
    func myImageButtonTapped(with index: IndexPath, view: AnimatedCheckmarkView) {
        HapticsManager.shared.selectionVibrate()
        let todo = self.tableViewCoreData[index.section].sortedItems[index.row - 1]

        todo.isMarked = !todo.isMarked
        
        if todo.isMarked == true {
            self.tableViewCoreData[index.section].totalMarked += 1
            view.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.7)
            view.isHidden = false
            do {
               try self.context.save()
            }
            catch{
                //error
            }
            tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            view.isHidden = true
            self.tableViewCoreData[index.section].totalMarked -= 1
            do {
               try self.context.save()
            }
            catch{
                //error
            }
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

Here is the function. Litterly everything in this works except the view.animate() that animates one random view instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create delegate to receive action from cell

```swift
protocol CellDelegate:AnyObject{
 /// pass arguments as per requirement 
 func cell(buttonDidPressed indexPath: IndexPath)
}
```

Now in your Cell class create weak reference of delegate

```swift
class Cell: UICollectionViewCell{
 weak var delegate: CellDelegate? = nil
 var indexPath: IndexPath!

/// code 

 @IBAction func buttonDidPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
  delegate?.cell(buttonDidPressed: indexPath)
 }
}
```

now in ur controller confirm this protocol

```swift
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate,
                          UICollectionViewDataSource,
                          CellDelegate{
   
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        // let cell : Cell dequeueReusableCell your cell
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.indexPath = indexPath
        return cell
    }

    func cell(buttonDidPressed indexPath: IndexPath){
     // your task on cell click
    }

}
```

You can also use closures in cell class alternative to protocol

Comment: This is kinda what I've done so far.
 If u had a view on top of that button that gets  unhidden and animated when you check todo. How would u write it? Because when I do I get the right index but I can't animate the view inside that cell. it always animate that view + random views etc. I'm clueless and been stuck on this for too long I feel

Comment: add gesture on that top view to receive click

Comment: If I do that I can't click the button right? Because the view will take the tap, they both are on the same exact spot

Comment: If you want to hide view which is on top of button
then add gesture on that top view to receive click and call same delegate method , this time view will be hidden so you can receive button click

else wrap button and view in container view and add gesture on container view

if you just wanna change image which is small then set that image in button 
``` playButton.setImage(image, forState: .Normal) ``` you can you states and different images

if there is no text in button set image as button background.

I hope this might help you.

Comment: Tried to problem solve this during the night and I came up with that the code works fine. The thing that screws the animation up is the tableView.reloadData() and I need that one to see total todos clicked. Maybe it will work with animation on completion -> relodData() gonna try when I get home and update you